# How to create HTML Table from Dataset and Datatables in C# by reading xml file

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0

I am very new to C#, I am reading XML file in C# and want to send xml file data as tabular form in mail.

XML File is:

```
<log>
    <logentry version='123'>
    <author>Dexter</author>
    <date>12 July 2017</date>
    <paths>
        <path action="M">C:\Desktop</path>
        <path action="N">C:\Documents\test.txt</path>
    </paths>
    <msg>Added New file</msg>
    </logentry>

    <logentry version='124'>
    <author>Dexter2</author>
    <date>11 July 2017</date>
    <paths>
        <path action="M">C:\Desktop\Test\mail.cp</path>
    </paths>
    <msg>Added New file in test folder</msg>
    </logentry>
</log>
```

And I am expecting table as:

[image]

And code:

```
 string filePath = "Log.xml";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(filePath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will create the DataTable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("version", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("author", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("msg", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("paths", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("action", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach(XElement logentry in doc.Descendants("logentry"))
            {
                foreach(XElement path in logentry.Descendants("path"))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        (int)logentry.Attribute("version"),
                        (DateTime)logentry.Element("date"),
                        (string)logentry.Element("author"),
                        (string)logentry.Element("msg"),
                        (string)path.FirstNode.ToString(),
                        (string)path.Attribute("action")
                    });
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want HTML for our mail, you just need to build a string containing the HTML. Loop through your data set, and for each row, create the HTML, using the values from the data set in the `<td>` tags.

Try this out, and if you have problems, post your code and explain the problem you are having with it.